# Compiler error when compiling runtime package using MSBuild on Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, delphi-xe2

I am in the process of upgrading our build server (Jenkins) to Delphi XE2. While compiling a runtime package the following error occurs:

```
ComponentsR.vrc(61): error RC2135: file not found: ComponentsR_Icon4.ico
```

There are no icons or resources in this runtime package, so I don't  know what to do with this message. What's the "vrc" file btw?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens while upgrading the dproj file of a package. The entry is created but the ico file is not (it is not used anyway).

Open the dproj file, search for the ico name and delete that entry.