# Migrate build server from Delphi XE to Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

How can I migrate my build server from Delphi XE to Delphi XE2?

Comment: Could you add to the question, what was the problem?

Comment: The problem is that if you just exchange the compiler, all your build scripts won't run without modifications.

Answer (score 9):

The first important thing to note, is that the parameter `DelphiWin32LibraryPath` changed its name to `DelphiLibraryPath` in Delphi XE2. So you have to change your buildscripts from something like

```
msbuild /p:DelphiWin32LibraryPath="..." ...
```

to

```
msbuild /p:DelphiLibraryPath="..." ...
```

Second, when migrating projects from XE, Delphi XE2 adds some resource references to the project file that won't compile on the build server (as pointed out by [this answer by Uwe Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413360/62391)). To fix this, open the `dproj` file in a text editor and remove the lines that reference an `ico` file called something like "ProjectName_Icon4.ICO".

The third nasty thing are the namespaces introduced in XE2. This will cause the build server to stop compiling with error messages such as

```
File "Windows.dcu" not found
```

This file is now called "Winapi.Windows". In order to avoid having to change all the uses clauses in your project you can tell the compiler to automatically add some namespaces implicitly:

```
msbuild /p:Namespace="System;System.Win;Winapi;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Data;Xml" ...
```

You might have to add some more namespaces that you use in your project.